Can not solve "unmet build dependencies: clang" error
I get unmet build dependencies: clang while trying to run the command ./gen-src-pkg.sh $(readlink -f ../outdir/modp_b64)
as part of the Fluoride BT stack installation procedure on Ubuntu 24.04
I have tried the installation procedure specified at Github llvm-project. I have tried specifying clang-12 version in the sudo get apt install clang-12
Both times at ./gen-src-pkg.sh $(readlink -f ../outdir/modp_b64) step I get the same error unmet build dependency: clang
